# Override 2 settings of textfield

Tags: html, css, textarea

I have the following HTML code to make a textarea.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
    <title>Title</title>  
    <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <link href="Office.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Notification.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Home.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.components.min.css">
    <style>
    .ms-TextField.ms-TextField--multiline .ms-TextField-field {
    font-family: monospace;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body class="ms-font-m">
    <div id="content-main">
    <div class="padding">
    <div class="ms-TextField ms-TextField--multiline">
        <textarea class="ms-TextField-field" id="myTextarea" spellcheck=false style="font-size: 16px;">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFG</textarea>
    </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is how the result looks like:

[image]

I would like to change 2 settings:

1) I want the height of the text area to be larger, like 8 rows for example

2) I want to remove the small triangle symbol at the right bottom of the area.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to remove the small triangle symbol at the right bottom of the
>   area.

- `resize:none` to hide the triangle, because you won't be able to resize the `textarea` anymore

> I want the height of the text area to be larger, like 8 rows for
>   example

- some `height` that could be in `px`/`em`/`rem`/`vh` to have around 8 rows.

---

```css
textarea {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size:16px;
  resize: none;
  height: 10rem;
  padding: 0
}
```

```html
<textarea class="ms-TextField-field" id="myTextarea" spellcheck=false>=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFG=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFG=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFG=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFG=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVW</textarea>
```

Comment: @SoftTimur `textarea` has by default `padding` of `1px` I just like to reset it.. nothing much..

Answer (score 1):

For textareas you can simply use rows="4" to increase the amount of rows.

And this css rule will disable the resize triangle

```
textarea {
   resize: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**1. I want the height of the text area to be larger, like 8 rows for example**

```
height: 8em;
```

**2. I want to remove the small triangle symbol at the right bottom of the area.**

```
resize: none;
```

**Snippet**

```css
.ms-TextField.ms-TextField--multiline .ms-TextField-field {
  font-family: monospace;
  height: 8em;
  resize: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="ms-TextField ms-TextField--multiline">
  <textarea class="ms-TextField-field" id="myTextarea" spellcheck=false style="font-size: 16px;">ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFG</textarea>
</div>
```